# chromium lldb debug not show string

Tags: chromium, lldb

I am debuging chromium in xcode,
and config the [../chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Tool/lldb/lldb_webkit.py](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/third_party/WebKit/Tools/lldb/lldb_webkit.py) in ~/.lldinit file，
but it not show the string correct, it only show the length of the string,can not show the content,
so it is inconvenient for debuging, I can not see the content of the string, this problem show in the picture.

[in the picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa2NT.png), [picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0SWu.png)

I hope the content is not empty, and show the string content currect, or is there a good way to show the content of string correct

Comment: I use this [code](https://codereview.chromium.org/24178002/), it also throw [error](https://i.imgur.com/joO26Ao.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The summary formatter code doesn't look right to me.  It does:

```
def WTFStringImpl_SummaryProvider(valobj, dict):
    provider = WTFStringImplProvider(valobj, dict)
    return "{ length = %d, is8bit = %d, contents = '%s' }" % (provider.get_length(), provider.is_8bit(), provider.to_string())
```

where the WTFStringImplProvider.is8_bit is:

```
def is_8bit(self):
    return self.valobj.GetChildMemberWithName('is8_bit_')
```

That is returning an SBValue, not an integer, so printing it with a %d format doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

Comment: this may not the main problem , I hava change the code to `bool(self.valobj.GetChildMemberWithName('is8_bit_').GetValue‌​AsUnsigned(0))`, it also can not show the string content, may be the object does not have the member `m_data8`, `m_data16`

Comment: Turning down the WTFAtomicString entity in your locals view should tell you that.  The data formatter's in lldb_webkit.py only have summary formatters, so they won't change the member display in the locals view (or in the results of `expr` and `frame var`.  You can also pass `--raw` to those commands to ensure you are seeing the raw data layout without any formatters.

Answer (score -1):

I created this issue (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1004272) to confirm that this is a bug, and have opened this code review to try to fix it: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1810444 .

This patch works in my local environment, you can give it a try.